# A batch file that search for a file, rename file and move it to another directory

Tags: batch-file, dos

```
@echo OFF
for /f "tokens=1-5 delims=/ " %%d in ("%date%") do rename "E2F.csv" E2F0%%g%%f%%e.csv
PAUSE
POPD
```

I want a batch script that does the following:

search for a file called E2F.csv

The script must rename `E2F.csv to E2F0YYMMDD`

Eg. `E2F0130517.csv`

The script must then `move E2F0130517.csv to E2F folder`.

I highly appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you can try this code:

```
set CURR_DATE=%DATE%
set MONTH=%CURR_DATE:~4,2%
set DAY=%CURR_DATE:~7,2%
set YEAR=%CURR_DATE:~12,2%
set VERSION=%YEAR%%MONTH%%DAY%
set source_folder = "C:\source"
set dest_folder = "C:\dest"
cd %source_folder%
if exist "%source_folder%\E2F.csv" (
echo "File Exists, Renaming and copying now"
move %source_folder%\E2F.csv  %dest_folder%\E2F%VERSION%.csv
) else (
echo "File Not Found"
)
```

Kindly, let me know if this solves your issue.

Comment: @Lamech : What is that ? .. comment ?

Comment: I changed the code a little bit....                       move "E2F.csv"  "E2F"\E2F0%VERSION%.cvs                             I want to move the file E2F.csv to a folder called E2F, and change its name to E2F0%VERSION%.csv but it is not working.....! Help???